# Remove the iron tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup

The tag [iron](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron) is used 29 times. Out of these, 17 are tagged [soldering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soldering) [iron](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron) which is definitely the wrong use of tags.

I suppose iron as in the material might be on-topic, when discussing various chemical aspects as in how well it conducts etc, but I kind of doubt we need a separate tag just for that. In-depth questions about the characteristics of iron should probably be posted at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ instead.

At the very least I propose that we remove the tag from the 17 incorrectly tagged solder iron questions.

Answer (score 3):

Iron is definitely 'too meta' and describes too many different things.

The questions fell into three categories:

- Iron soldering: These I remapped to [iron-soldering-station](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-soldering-station) there were at least 9 that fell into this category. Most users had a double tag of [iron](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron) and [soldering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soldering) attached to these questions.
- Iron Core: There were 7 questions, I created a tag called [iron-core](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-core) and *merged the tag [iron](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron) to [iron-core](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-core) since these had the most questions tagged for iron. (If a user types in iron, they probably mean iron core. This also forces users to consider which tag they mean instead of just an ambiguous 'iron' tag.
- Iron Chloride: 1 Question, created a tag for [iron-chloride](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron-chloride), which is used for etching.

Comment: R.e. the last point, wouldn't `[ferric-chloride]` be a better option for a tag?

Comment: Yes, but for the people who type in iron, they'll get iron-chloride, with tags it's a user interface game

Comment: On reflection it seems wiki uses iron-chloride, so shows what I know.